# Read specific character from a file in shell

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

I created a small script that outputs the number of connections into a file (which looks something like this):

Active connections: 1

I am trying to read and store the number (1) in a variable for further processing in Bourne shell. This number can change if there are more connections. Can anyone help me achieve this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple like:

```
 myvar=$(echo "Active connections: 1" | awk '{print $NF}')
 echo $myvar
 Output:
 1
```

Comment: I updated my main question because I think I wasn't very clear. Sorry about that.